# Intersection of two arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to search in a big array for different id from another array and print all intersections of those two arrays

I want to map through my bigTable and  I want to create another array of correspondence, each found element must contain all fields+tableName+tableID like this :

```js
const output = [{
    ID: 1234,
    title: 'title1',
    TableName: 'loramIpsum',
    TableId: 11,
  },
  {
    ID: 98523,
    title: 'mylasttitle',
    TableName: 'table2',
    TableId: 87545,
  },
  {
    ID: 97766,
    title: 'mylastdata',
    TableName: 'table2',
    TableId: 87545,
  },
]
```

I've create a function but I think there is another best and sample solution, this is my function :

```js
const getResult = (wantedData, bigArray) => {
  return wantedData.flatMap((id) =>
    bigArray.flatMap((family) =>
      family.Tables.flatMap((table) => {
        let item = table.myDatas.find((el) => el.ID === id);
        if (item) {
          item.Table = table.TableName;
          item.familyId = family.GridId;
          return item;
        }
      }).filter((result) => result !== undefined)
    )
  );
};
console.log(getResult(wantedData, bigArray))
```

```html
<script>
  const wantedData = [1235, 98523, 97766];


  const bigArray = [{
      bigArrayId: 1111,
      Tables: [{
        TableId: 11,
        TableName: 'loramIpsum',
        myDatas: [{
            ID: 1234,
            title: 'title1',
          },
          {
            ID: 1235,
            title: 'title2',
          },
        ],
      }, ],
    },
    {
      bigArrayId: 674665,
      Tables: [{
        TableId: 87545,
        TableName: 'table2',
        myDatas: [{
            ID: 98523,
            title: 'mylasttitle',
          },
          {
            ID: 24134,
            title: 'alex',
          },
          {
            ID: 97766,
            title: 'mylastdata',
          },
        ],
      }, ],
    },
  ];
</script>
```

Any help please ? Can I do it with recursive function ?

Comment: I reformatted you question so it is readable and made a snippet. but the snippet gives console errors

Comment: Thank your for your formatting, yes sometimes it show an error, I still don't know why, When I'm triyng to find in myDatas array I get this error

Comment: Change to `let item = table.myDatas?.find((el) => el.ID === id);` since you do not have myDatas in the last entry

Comment: I edited my array, now it work's for my example, I want to know if there is another best solutions to refactoration now :)

Comment: So you are saying that your code works but you are looking for a better solution?

Comment: How better? Shorter? Faster? More elegant?

Comment: Faster and more elegant, because I'm using 3 flatMap and I want to use another solution :)

Comment: Filter the table first using the wantedData as driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to solve this problem in two steps:

- First, create a flat array of tables
- Then filter the array by conditions

```js
const bigArray=[{bigArrayId:1111,Tables:[{TableId:11,TableName:"loramIpsum",myDatas:[{ID:1234,title:"title1"},{ID:1235,title:"title2"}]}]},{bigArrayId:674665,Tables:[{TableId:87545,TableName:"table2",myDatas:[{ID:98523,title:"mylasttitle"},{ID:24134,title:"alex"},{ID:97766,title:"mylastdata"}]}]}];

const wantedData = [1235, 98523, 97766];

const flatTables = bigArray.flatMap(({ Tables }) => 
  Tables.flatMap(({ myDatas, TableId, TableName }) => 
    myDatas.map((data) => ({ ...data, TableId, TableName })) ));

const result = flatTables.filter(({ ID }) => wantedData.includes(ID));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you do it something like this you'll be able to map after you've found the right things rather than mapping everything and then filtering that result:

```js
const bigArray = [{ bigArrayId: 1111, Tables: [{ TableId: 11, TableName: 'loramIpsum', myDatas: [{ ID: 1234, title: 'title1', }, { ID: 1235, title: 'title2', }, ], }, ], }, { bigArrayId: 674665, Tables: [{ TableId: 87545, TableName: 'table2', myDatas: [{ ID: 98523, title: 'mylasttitle', }, { ID: 24134, title: 'alex', }, { ID: 97766, title: 'mylastdata', }, ], }, ], }, ];

const wantedData = [1235, 98523, 97766];

const wanted_set = new Set(wantedData);

const push_concat = (arr1, arr2) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++)
    arr1.push(arr2[i]);
  
  return arr1;
};

const res = bigArray.reduce(
  (acc, { Tables }) =>
    push_concat(acc, 
      Tables.flatMap(({ TableId, TableName, myDatas }) =>
        myDatas
            .filter(({ ID }) => wanted_set.has(ID))
            .map(({ ID, title }) => ({ ID, title, TableId, TableName }))
      )
    ),
  []
);


console.log(res);
```